# beginner trying to apply a tax rate to an individual's income

Tags: javascript, html

> Your Javascript must follow the following guidelines:
>
> 1. If the income is $70,000 or above the tax rate starts at 70% (the % sign will not show)
> 2. If the income is $20,000 or below the tax rate starts at 10% (the % sign will not show)
> 3. Otherwise the tax rate starts at 25%

I know there are likely 1000 mistakes but anything that would help me get through this question would help

my function isn't working and i am pretty sure im not even on the right track

```
<html>
<head>
<script language = "JavaScript">

function ()
{
var IncomeInput,
TaxRateCalc;

IncomeInput = parseInt(document.TaxInfo.Income.value);

if (IncomeInput>=70000)
{
    TaxRateCalc = "70";
}
else if (IncomeInput=<20000)
{
    TaxRateCalc = "10";
}
else ()
{
    TaxRateCalc = "25"; 
}
document.TaxInfo.TaxRate.value = TaxRateCalc;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
The Taxman
</center>

<form name = "TaxInfo">
<table border = "3">
Your Tax Information<br>
<tr><td>Income</td> <td> <input name = "Income" value = "10000000" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>RRSP</td> <td> <input name = "RRSP" value ="0" size = "20"></td> </tr>
<tr><td>Tax Rate</td> <td> <input name = "TaxRate" value = "" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Taxes Paid</td> <td> <input name = "TaxesPaid" value = "0" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
<tr><td>Refund or Due</td> <td> <input name = "RefundOrDue"  value = "0"size = "20"> </td> </tr> 
</table>
</form>

<form name = "Extra Deductions">
Extra Deductions-
Children <input name = "Children" type = "radio">
Spouse <input name = "Spouse" type = "radio">
Both <input name = "Both" type = "radio">
None <input name = "None" checked type = "radio">
</form>

<form name = OldPeople >
Over age 65? <input name = "Over age 65?" type = "checkbox" >
</form>

<form name = "Selection">
Special Cases
<select name="SpecialCases">

    <option value ="None"> None </option>
    <option value ="Hardship Claimed"> Hardship Claimed </option>
    <option value ="Mercy"> Mercy </option>
    <option value ="Lawyer"> Lawyer </option>
</select>
</form>

<form name = "buttons">
<input type = "button" value = "Calculate your tax" onclick = "">
<input type = "button" value = "Clear Display Area" onclick= "aloop">
</form>

<form name = "YourTaxRate">
Your Tax Rate<br> <textarea name = "TaxRate" rows = "15" cols = "25"> </textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you read **all** the articles [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) first, it will take only couple of hours.

Comment: yes sir.. unfortunately

Comment: I post a very simple example, please let me know if works for you.

Comment: @skobaljic noooononono please don't link and suggest W3Schools tutorials to Anyone. They are not related to W3C in any way, also the site in not driven by an open community and all they do is putting ads and selling diplomas that don't worth a dime. It's not my opinion. It's a fact. Still today I've encountered tons of lousy written techincal documentation over there, and for an open minded beginner it's a shame to immediately put wrong information as base. There are thousands of other great tutorials online. Hey, there are also *books*! you know?!

Comment: Instead or writing such a long comment you could suggest few sites?

Comment: @skobaljic :) Exactly, it would be a too long list. For technical informations you have MDN as (frankly) the best resource. For all other sites... well simply block w3schools from the Google results and you'll be amazed with what you can find.

Comment: Well if you insist, there is a good reason why w3schools is on top of google list in last 15 years. I have never noticed ads there until you mentioned for last decade. It has a good navigation, great examples with Try it yourself snippets. In one word it is best place for beginners. Sometimes I block ad domains, but would never block such an Internet jewel as w3schools is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how much of that was a template. Oh by the way, have faith in yourself. I don't know how much of that you wrote yourself, but for the function itself, only the `IncomeInput<=20000` comparator needed to be switched.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>

<script>

function calcTax() {

    var IncomeInput, TaxRateCalc;

    IncomeInput = parseInt(document.TaxInfo.Income.value);

    if (IncomeInput>=70000)
    {
        TaxRateCalc = "70";
    }
    else if (IncomeInput<=20000)
    {
        TaxRateCalc = "10";
    }
    else
    {
        TaxRateCalc = "25"; 
    }
    document.YourTaxRate.TaxRate.value = TaxRateCalc;

}

</script>

<center>
The Taxman
</center>


<form name = "TaxInfo">
    <table border = "3">
        Your Tax Information<br>
        <tr><td>Income</td> <td> <input name = "Income" value = "10000000" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td>RRSP</td> <td> <input name = "RRSP" value ="0" size = "20"></td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Tax Rate</td> <td> <input name = "TaxRate" value = "" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Taxes Paid</td> <td> <input name = "TaxesPaid" value = "0" size = "20"> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td>Refund or Due</td> <td> <input name = "RefundOrDue"  value = "0"size = "20"> </td> </tr> 
    </table>
</form>

<form name = "Extra Deductions">
    Extra Deductions-
    Children <input name = "Children" type = "radio">
    Spouse <input name = "Spouse" type = "radio">
    Both <input name = "Both" type = "radio">
    None <input name = "None" checked type = "radio">
</form>

<form name = "OldPeople" >
    Over age 65? <input name = "Over age 65?" type = "checkbox" >
</form>

<form name = "Selection">
    Special Cases
    <select name="SpecialCases">

        <option value ="None"> None </option>
        <option value ="Hardship Claimed"> Hardship Claimed </option>
        <option value ="Mercy"> Mercy </option>
        <option value ="Lawyer"> Lawyer </option>
    </select>
</form>

<form name = "buttons">
    <input type = "button" value = "Calculate your tax!" onclick = "calcTax()" />
    <input type = "button" value = "Clear Display Area" onclick = "" />
</form>

<form name = "YourTaxRate">
    Your Tax Rate<br> <textarea name = "TaxRate" rows = "15" cols = "25"> </textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: appreciate the help and believe it or not all me i just cant seem to grasp the concept of functions very well

Comment: What? radix is an optional parameter, why would I want to change from base 10 in this example?

Comment: No, use it always (BTW, it was not me to remove my suggestion above...).

Comment: So than I'll repeat again, try always to use the `radix` parameter. Respect the grammar just like in any other language.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var income = document.getElementById("income").value;
  var taxRateCalc;
  if (income == "") {
    alert("Please type a valid income.");
  } else {
    if (income >= 70000) {
      taxRateCalc = "70";
    }
    else if (income <= 20000) {
      taxRateCalc = "10";
    }
    else {
      taxRateCalc = "25"; 
    }
    document.getElementById("taxRate").value = taxRateCalc;
  }
}
```

```html
Income: <input type="text" id="income">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Validate Income</button><br><br>
Tax Rate: <input type="text" id="taxRate" readonly>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, a lot better!